# How to get device path and mount path using usbdi callbacks?

Tags: usb, qnx, qnx-neutrino

I am in the progress of implementing a service which will detect usb plugin/removal using usbdi callback functions. Callback function has a parameter "usbd_device_instance_t * usbInstance" from which i can get device vendor id,product id and the device class information. But how do i get a mount point in case of a mass storage device and a device path in case of a HID device?

Answer (score 0):

In QNX 6.6 and 7.0, usblauncher writes a map of detected devices, launched drivers, and their arguments such as mount point to the PPS tree.  The [USB Launcher Service reference manual](http://www.qnx.com/developers/docs/7.0.0/#com.qnx.doc.dev_pub.ref_guide/topic/usblauncher_otg.html) has complete documentation on the location and formatting of these entries.  You could scan them to find out what high level details you need.

That said, the usblauncher script engine also provides a place where you could add custom on-connect commands directly; that might be easier than writing a new service.

Comment: How to identify the PID of the device object? so that i will be able identify the driver object belongs to the device object. How the device object, driver object and mount objects are related? Is there any way to identify the driver object and mount object of a device object without reading each file inside it?